# I have installed 18.04 but python2 did not come with it

Tags: python

I am kind of new in linux environment, I had a 18.10 and I overwrite a 18.04 on it. Now I have a fresh installation of 18.04.

Before installing anything, I have checked by typing `python` to terminal, but it said I don't have python but I have python3. Then I typed `pyton3` and yes, I have python3.6.x.

So, as far as I know, somethings on ubuntu still depends on python2. So why there is not a default python2 on this new installation?

Comment: Have you considered just doing `sudo apt-get install python-all`?  That will install Python 2.  But around the 18.04 cycle we knew things would start to transition to Python 3 - so most of the Python 2 requisite software that was part of a standard install was converted to Python 3.  Python 2 is therefore not default-installed.

Comment: @ThomasWard I was not asking how can I install python2, indeed. I was wondering why it did not come with it. You kind of answered me, thanks.

Comment: Well, Python 3 is the standard since Py2 died earlier this year.

Comment: @ThomasWard so, why they did not make "python" keyword to refer python3 by default? Do I have to use it as python3 and pip3 all the time?

Comment: Because Python upstream has consistently stated that `python` is reserved for Python 2 and `python3` is reserved for Python 3.  (And because there's still packages that need Python 2 in 18.04 and require `python` to be Python 2)

Comment: @ThomasWard hmmm, so, If I don't manually install python2 now, it will be installed automatically when I want to install a package which depends on python2, am i right?

Comment: It should, yes.